# Changing ansible loop due to v2.11 deprecation

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm running a playbook which defined several packages to install via `apt`:

```
    - name: Install utility packages common to all hosts
      apt:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        autoclean: yes
      with_items:
        - aptitude
        - jq
        - curl
        - git-core
        - at
...
```

A recent ansible update on my system now renders this message concerning the playbook above:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "apt" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of
 using a loop to supply multiple items and specifying `name: {{ item }}`, please use `name: [u'aptitude', 
u'jq', u'curl', u'git-core', u'at', u'heirloom-mailx', u'sudo-ldap', u'sysstat', u'vim', u'at', u'ntp', 
u'stunnel', u'sysstat', u'arping', u'net-tools', u'lshw', u'screen', u'tmux', u'lsscsi']` and remove the loop.
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, Ansible now wants this list of packages as an array which leaves this:

```
name: [u'aptitude', u'jq', u'curl', u'git-core', u'at','heirloom-mailx', u'sudo-ldap', u'sysstat', u'vim', u'at', u'ntp',u'stunnel', u'sysstat', u'arping', u'net-tools', u'lshw', u'screen', u'tmux', u'lsscsi']
```

Is there a better way? Just seems like I'll be scrolling right forever in VIM trying to maintain this. Either that, or word wrap it and deal with a word-cloud of packages.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can code the array in YAML style to make it more readable:

```
- name: Install utility packages common to all hosts
  apt:
    name:
      - aptitude
      - jq
      - curl
      - git-core
      - at
    state: present
    autoclean: yes
```

Comment: Thank you. Much better!

Comment: Add doc for reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-name

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question and it looks like each set of packages with the same states will have to be their own block. Looking at Ansible's documentation, they have a block for each state as an example so I took that example, cut up my packages based off their states and followed ignacio's example and it ended up working perfectly.

So basically it would look like this

```
- name: Install packages required for log-deployment
  apt:
    name:
      - gcc
      - python-devel
    state: latest
    autoclean: yes

- name: Install packages required for log-deployment
  apt:
    name:
      - python
      - mariadb
      - mysql-devel
    state: installed
```

Hope that makes sense and helps!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this exact same problem , but with a much longer list of apps , held in a vars file. This is the code I implemented to get around that problem. The list of the apps is placed into the "apps" variable and Ansible iterates over that.

```
- name: Install default applications
  apt:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: latest
  loop: "{{ apps }}"
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' or ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
  tags:
     - instapps
```

The file holding the list of apps to install is in the Defaults directory in the role directory for this task - namely the "common" role directory.

```
roles
    - common
      - Defaults
        - main.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

For a record, you can have this written this way:

```yaml
    - name: Install utility packages common to all hosts
      apt:
        state: present
        autoclean: yes
        pkg: [
          "aptitude",
          "jq",
          "curl",
          "git-core",
          "at",
        ]
```

however if you are upgrading existing roles to new `apt`'s requirements, Ignacio's accepted answer is far better as all you need is just to add some indentation to already existing entries.